# how to extract ARGB color for pixel

Tags: python

i converted image into 2D array using asarray, how to extract ARGB color value of pixel from this array and check RGB, HSV, Ycbcr values ?
i found this method on 
[this article](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1708/1708.02694.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It's also pretty simple to implement the `rgb_to_hsv`, but `colorsys` is included in the standard library.

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import colorsys

def getYCrCb(r, g, b):
    y = 0.299 * r + 0.287 * g + 0.11 * b
    return (y, r - y, b - y)

img = np.array(Image.open('/path/to/image')) # equivalent asarray
print(img.shape) # height, width, RGB (one for each channel means 3)
r, g, b = img[200, 200] # pixel. Coordinate from top, then coordinate from left
print(r, g, b)   # 73 70 39 for example
print(colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b))  # (0.15196078022321066, 0.46575344, 73) in the same example
print(getYCrCb(r, g, b))             # (46.207, 26.793, -7.207000000000001) in the same example
```